# Need to exit a loop and fix print order error (basic calculator)

Tags: java, loops, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator which activates upon request. I've had no problems activating the calculator, but I've struggled with the inputs etc.
I've finally managed to (kind of) get it working, but I need help making it exit the loop, and print things in the correct order. (more details below). 
Here's the code for this part:

```
public void calculate(){

    for(int i = 1; i<2; i++){

        print("calculator activated" + "\n" + "please input your first value" + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));

        try {
            wait(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        } 
        catch (Exception e1) {
        }

        input.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String text1 = input.getText();
                double value1 = Double.parseDouble(text1);

                print("please inout your second value" + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));



                try {
                    wait(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                } 
                catch (Exception e1) {
                }

                input.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String text2 = input.getText();
                double value2 = Double.parseDouble(text2);

                double add = value1 + value2;
                double subtract = value1 - value2;
                double multiply = value1 * value2;
                double divide = value1 / value2;

            print("add = " + add + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));
            print("subtract = " + subtract + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));
            print("multiply = " + multiply + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));
            print("divide = " + divide + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));




            }
        });
    }
        });
    }
}
```

When it runs, my 'program' is like a command prompt (whenever you type something and hit enter, it prints it out), and when you input the command "calculate", this part of the code begins. It asks for the first value, and when you put it in, it asks for the second value before printing out the first value. I've tried:

```
sleep(1000);
```

But it seemed to have no effect.
[This also happens when inputting the second value; it prints the calculations before the second value is printed.]

Furthermore, after it prints the calculations, (still before it prints the second value) it says "please input your second value" again. I think this could be an issue with leaving the 'for' loop, but really, I have no idea.

I can't add images due to being a new user (need 10 rep)

Comment: I don't see where you are actually printing the inputted values. Was it just omitted in your post?

Comment: This tutorial snippet might help you out with your issues: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-take-input-from-user.

Comment: You can't input values from a UI with a `for` loop like that. Think event based processing, not procedural processing.

Comment: That's not entirely true, @ElliottFrisch, you can build an array of input from a for loop and perform the calculations and print the result after the loop is terminated, but it has to be done properly. Usually the gate keeper is user input to determine how many pieces of input the user wants to enter, then stick a prompt at the beginning of the loop counting it down.

Comment: The printing part isn't in this post. It's nothing fancy:

Comment: print(text + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13);

Comment: @CSS OP has one `input`. And he's looping with an anonymous `ActionListener` on the same `input`. I realize that it's possible to construct a loop that will work in a UI, I suppose I should have been more explicit about the antecedent for *that*.

Comment: @CSS I just had a proper look at that tutorial, and from what I can see, it's just an alternative way of doing what I've already done. Thanks anyway :)